# Laravel, inserting one-to-many relationship with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model `Item` with a has-many relationsship with `points` like this:

```
public function points() {
    return $this->has_many('Point');
}
```

Then in my controller I want to set some data when a user is posting an `Item`. So I do it like this:

```
        $item = new Item;
        $item->author = $author;
        $item->description = '';
        $item->link = $link;
        $item->source = $url['host'];
        $item->title = $title;
        $item->url_encoded = $url;  
        $item->save(); 
        $points = array(
            array('ip' => $ip)
        );

        $item->points()->save($points);
```

However this gives me an error which I seem to get everytime I try to save a `Point` which is:

```
Array to string conversion
```

What can I do to insert my `Point` with the property `item_id` correct?

Comment: I don't use 3 but if this is the same as 4 I think you need to be making an instance? `$item->points()->save(new Point($points));` ?

Comment: @Robbo yes I tried that first, I am using the example http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#inserting-related-models which suprisingly often doesn't work. Getting the same error message if I create a new instance.

Comment: There is another method you can use. Do the item the same but when it comes to the point you can do `$point = new Point(['ip' => $ip]);` and then `$point->save();` after which you attach the point to the item with `$item->points()->attach($point->id)`. Note I wrote that from memory and it might be wrong...

Comment: after reading the docs for 3 what you are doing is like exactly the same? Your error might be to do with something else?

Comment: That attach method seems to work well. I've got another error though, but that has nothing to do with any model. If you make your comment as an answer I will accept it. I am doing the same by having an initiated model Item and then is trying to save some points related to it.

Comment: Well in fact, no it didn't work :/ Giving me the same error. It seemed to work at first because I forgot a semicolon after `$item->points()->attach($point->id);`. This line gives me the same error `Array to string conversion -> /laravel/database/connection.php on line 256`

Comment: well next go you can try using insert, `$item->points()->insert(['ip' => $ip]);`... not sure if it will work though, once again.

Comment: Hehe that was the first thing I tried :/ same error message. I am beginning to ask myself why I didn't choose a framework with better documentation.

Comment: I have even tried to just initiate a new Point and then fill it with data and run a save. Still the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After slowly going through the code line by line I noticed that the error occurred when saving the Item in the first place. A column had a variable that got overwritten by an array. Therefore I got this error message.

It was very confusing though because I added the new code when I added the Point. Since there was no trace from where the error came from it was an easy thing to miss.